# Where <column name> is not null

Tags: sql

This is the question: Select from the Person Table the BusinessEntityID, Title, the first letter of First Name, first letter of MiddleName, and Last Name (label as Full Name) where there isn’t NULL in any part of the name.

This is what I have thus far:

```
 Use AdventureWorks2008R2;
    Select BusinessEntityID,SUBSTRING(Title,1,3)+' '+SUBSTRING(FirstName,1,1)+' '+
    SUBSTRING(MiddleName,1,1)+' '+ LastName as 'Full Name'
    From Person.Person
    Where LastName IS NOT NULL;
```

However the LastName column shows NULL values

Comment: Are they actually `NULL`? Or just a string `"null"` or `''`

Comment: Does it show `NULL` values, or does it show `''` (empty string) values?  The two are very different.

Comment: How are you confirming 'LastName' IS NULL? You aren't selecting that value. Perhaps they are just empty strings, which is not the same as NULL.

Comment: `SUBSTRING(<column>, 1, 1)` is dangerous for non-Latin character sets (some accented characters, some entire languages).  Will that be a problem for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any of the columns you are concatenating together is NULL, the result will be NULL. You have to filter out Title, FirstName and MiddleName as well.

```
Use AdventureWorks2008R2;
SELECT BusinessEntityID,SUBSTRING(Title,1,3)+' '+SUBSTRING(FirstName,1,1)+' '+
SUBSTRING(MiddleName,1,1)+' '+ LastName as 'Full Name'
From Person.Person
Where LastName IS NOT NULL AND
      Title IS NOT NULL AND 
      FirstName IS NOT NULL AND
      MiddleName IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: That works thank you for helping it makes sense what you said I didn't even think about that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
Use AdventureWorks2008R2;
Select BusinessEntityID,SUBSTRING(Title,1,3)+' '+SUBSTRING(FirstName,1,1)+' '+
SUBSTRING(MiddleName,1,1)+' '+ LastName as 'Full Name'
From Person.Person
Where LastName IS NOT NULL AND LastName != ''
```